# How to sum column values of items with shared substring in first column using bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I am trying to sum values across rows of a dataframe for rows which have a shared *substring* in the first column. The data looks like this:

```
ID Data_1 Data_2 Data_3 Data_4 
SRW8002300_T01 1 2 3 4
SRW8002300_T02 1 2 3 4
SRW8002300_T03 1 2 3 4
SRW8004500_T01 1 2 3 4
SRW8004500_T02 1 2 3 4
SRW8006000_T01 1 2 3 4
```

I want to sum the 2nd to 5th column values when the first part of the ID (the part before the underscore) is shared. So the above would become:

```
ID Data_1 Data_2 Data_3 Data_4 
SRW8002300 3 6 9 12
SRW8004500 2 4 6 8
SRW8006000 1 2 3 4
```

So far I've got an awk command that can strip the IDs of the string after the underscore:

`awk '{print $1}' filename | awk -F'_' '{print $1}'`

And another to sum column values if the value in the first column is shared:

`awk '{a[$1]+=$2;b[$1]+=$3;c[$1]+=$4;d[$1]+=$5} END {for (i in a) print i, a[i], b[i], c[i], d[i]}' filename`

However, I am struggling to combine these two commands to create a new dataframe with summed values for the shared IDs.

I usually code in python but am trying to get into the habit of writing bash scripts for these sorts of tasks.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: wrt `am trying to get into the habit of writing bash scripts for these sorts of tasks` - awk is not bash, it's a completely separate tool just like python is. The only difference in that regard is that awk comes as standard on all UNIX boxes unlike python, perl, ruby, etc. It would be completely inappropriate to try to use bash or any other shell for text manipulation.

Comment: Yep that makes sense! Thanks for the clarification. I suppose I am trying to use awk then (or a different tool?) that will do these routine jobs faster than a python script.

Comment: idk if doing anything in awk would be significantly faster than doing it in python, it'd just be more portable as you could write it in POSIX awk syntax so it'd work as-is on every UNIX box without needing to install non-standard tools. You won't find any tool that'll do general purpose text manipulation any faster than awk though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your key values are contiguous as shown in your sample input:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==1 { print; next }
{
    curr = $1
    sub(/_.*/,"",curr)

    if ( curr != prev ) {
        prt()
    }

    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
        sum[i] += $i
    }

    prev = curr
}

END { prt() }

function prt() {
    if ( prev != "" ) {
        printf "%s%s", prev, OFS
        for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
            printf "%d%s", sum[i], (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)
        }
        delete sum
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
ID Data_1 Data_2 Data_3 Data_4
SRW8002300 3 6 9 12
SRW8004500 2 4 6 8
SRW8006000 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Thank you for your post Ed. Unfortunately, the shared IDs are not always contiguous though...

Comment: You can always sort your input so they are (`{ head -1 file; tail +2 file | sort; } | awk '...'` or put the awk right after the sort and remove the NR==1 block) . Otherwise you'd need a 2 pass approach either reading the input twice or storing all values in an array to process in the END section like you already have in the script in your question so I assume you can figure out how to massage my script similarly if you want to do it that way.

Comment: I got it working into my workflow with this solution. It is also great that the solution is flexible as to the number of columns as I have many of these files to process, all with a different number of data columns. Cheers!!